# Renault Clio 5 motor oil

Tags: engine, oil, renault, clio

Which type of motor oil is suitable for Renault Clio 5 sce 65 with petrol engine?
I think a 5w30 but i don't know what type.
Maintenance and warranty sheet : norm RN 17 , engine oil volume 3.40 L , degrees of use according to the outside temperature -15c -20c -25c 5w30 and -30c 0w40 , manufacturer recommends castrol oil.

Comment: Do you have the Owners Manual?  This information should be there.  I searched for an online copy but didn't find it but it will be available from Renault.

Comment: i have it but only recommends castrol oil for engine no specification

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair :o)

Comment: There is nothing special about Castrol.  Castrol oil is going to meet the same API specs as any other oil you might buy for gasoline powered automotive use.

Answer (score 0):

The current spec is API-SN or SN+, either of which meets or exceeds all the requirements for your Renault.  You can purchase Castrol if you like and I've found that often that brand is reasonably priced.  Sometimes other brands are on sale.

Comment: I'm from europe , do you know ACEA specification. The engine doesn't have turbine and particle filter.

Comment: Same answer, Castrol is a mass market oil not some specialty type.  Check out a bottle of it in your market and see what specs are listed.  Then see if there is another brand with the same specs available at a better price.

Comment: API SN+ is developed for turbocharged engines and i found for clio 5 sce65 a genuine renault rn 17 castrol 5w30.

Answer (score 0):

A complete answer for clio 5 sce 65 engine oil must be on the label : norm RN 17 , ACEA C3 , API SN .
Norm RN 17 : Compatible for all engine gasoline (except RS and ALPINE) and for new diesel engines Euro 6 from June 2018 and Diesel not equipped with FAP. Backward compatibility on RN 0700 and RN0710 standards.